# How to not count punctuation between words

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to count variable of say an apostrophe counting with words such as "shouldn't" only.

For example "I shouldn't do that" counts once
But " 'I will not do that' " counts zero

Basically how can i use counts to count apostrophes in words and not quotes.

I haven't been able to try much successfully. I can only use the basic for loop to count every apostrophe but can't narrow down specifically.

```
for sentence in split_sentences: 
        for w in sentence:
            for p in punctuation:
                if p == w:
                    if word in counts:
                        counts[p] += 1 
                    else:
                        counts[p] = 1

                else:
                    pass
```

With a given list of words, It should count only in words not around word.
So "Shouldn't" will count but "'should'" will not.

Comment: What about `"Chris' house"`. Here the apostrophe is in a word, but on the end like a quotation so how would you like to handle this?

Comment: "In addition, your program should also count single-quote and hyphen, but only under certain circumstances. Specifically, your program should count single-quote marks, but only when they appear as apostrophes surrounded by letters, i.e. indicating a contraction such as "shouldn't" or "won't"." - This is what I was given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if it is **inside** the word:

```
for sentence in split_sentences: 
        for w in sentence:
            for p in punctuation:
                if p in w and w[0] != p and w[-1] != p:
                    if word in counts:
                        counts[p] += 1 
                    else:
                        counts[p] = 1
                else:
                    pass
```

The important line is this `if p in w and w[0] != p and w[-1] != p:`
We have 3 rules for it to count:

- The puntuation `p` is in the word `2`
- The word `w` does not start (`w[0]`) by the punctuation `p`
- The word `w` does not ends (`w[-1]`) by the punctuation `p`

A more pythonic way of doing such would be to use the str available methods, `endswith` and `startswith`:

```
...
if p in w and not w.startswith(p) and not w.endswith(p):
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice! May I ask. If I want to count "-" in words how do i prevent it from counting "--" such as "World--four" as 2.

Comment: @FraserGilbert with this rules it should not count it twice, since it just checks if the puntuation is there not how many times it is.

Comment: Ahh makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression `[a-zA-Z]'[a-zA-Z]` to find all single quotes that are surrounded by letters.

The requirement for the hyphen isn't completely clear to me. If it has the same requirement (i.e. it only counts when surrounded by letters) than using the regular expression `[a-zA-Z]['-][a-zA-Z]` will do the trick: it will count quotes as well as hyphens.

If you should count *all* hyphens, then you could just use the [str.count](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method (e.g. 
`"test-string".count("-")` returns 1).

Here is some example code, assuming the hyphens must also be counted only if they are surrounded by letters:

```
import re

TEST_SENTENCES = (
    "I shouldn't do that",
    "'I will not do that'",
    "Test-hyphen"
)

PATTERN = re.compile("[a-zA-Z]['-][a-zA-Z]")

for sentence in TEST_SENTENCES:
    print(len(PATTERN.findall(sentence)))
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
```